# MySql Query Optimization with LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a MySQL query to optimized because when this query runs it increase MySQL process CPU usage to 100%. So I did some modification on that query and now it decrease its running time but still CPU usage is near to 100%. I index all search fields in both tables.

These 'milestone_and_events' and 'milestone_and_events_reminders' has one to many relationship ('milestone_and_events' have one or more 'milestone_and_events_reminders') and 'milestone_and_events_reminders' table have nearly 1.5 million records.

Is there any way to further optimize this query, can any one give me a guide ?? thank you

This is original query

```
SELECT MAE.*
     , MAER.reminder_user_id
     , MAER.reminder_type
     , MAER.id as reminder_id 
  FROM milestone_and_events AS MAE 
  LEFT 
  JOIN milestone_and_events_reminders MAER 
    ON MAE.id = MAER.milestone_and_events_id 
 WHERE MAER.alert_time < '$currentTime'
   AND MAER.issued ! = 1 
   AND MAE.completed = 0
 GROUP 
    BY MAE.id
     , MAER.reminder_user_id
     , MAER.reminder_type
```

This is my current query

```
$currentTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$query = 'SELECT MAE.id, MAE.time, MAER.reminder_user_id, MAER.reminder_type, MAER.id AS reminder_id 
            FROM milestone_and_events AS MAE 
            LEFT JOIN milestone_and_events_reminders MAER ON 
            MAE.id = MAER.milestone_and_events_id AND 
            MAER.issued =0 AND 
            MAER.alert_time < "' . $currentTime . '" AND 
            MAE.completed =0 
            WHERE MAER.reminder_type != "onTime"
            GROUP BY MAER.milestone_and_events_id,MAER.reminder_user_id,MAER.reminder_type';
```

**UPDATE 1**

this 'milestone_and_events' table have nearly 200 entries.

```
CREATE TABLE `milestone_and_events` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `description` varchar(250) NOT NULL, 
 `time` datetime NOT NULL,
 `attached_type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `attached_type_value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
 `completed` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
 `type` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1', 
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `time` (`time`), 
 KEY `completed` (`completed`),
 KEY `id` (`id`,`completed`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=154 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

'milestone_and_events_reminders' table have nearly 1.5 million entries.

```
CREATE TABLE `milestone_and_events_reminders` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `reminder_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `milestone_and_events_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `alert_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `issued` tinyint(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `reminder_type` enum('upComming','delayed','onTime') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`reminder_user_id`),
  KEY `reminder_type` (`reminder_type`),
  KEY `issued` (`issued`),
  KEY `milestone_and_events_id` (`milestone_and_events_id`, `issued`,`reminder_type`),
   CONSTRAINT `milestone_and_events_reminders_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY                       (`milestone_and_events_id`) 
   REFERENCES `milestone_and_events` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3323544 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each relevant table.  How big is each table?  Do you need `LEFT`?

Comment: @RickJames I add `SHOW CREATE TABLE` queries and table sizes. in this query I try to fetch all relevant entries from `milestone_and_events_reminders` table. so I think that query need `LEFT`

Comment: I don't see the indexes you added based on Gordon's Answer.  Nor do I see the Engine.  Please _perform_ `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: updated with my latest table query :)

Comment: Backwards:  KEY `id` (`id`,`completed`) -- The order of columns in an INDEX matters!

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
SELECT MAE.id, MAE.time, MAER.reminder_user_id, MAER.reminder_type, MAER.id AS reminder_id 
FROM milestone_and_events AS MAE LEFT JOIN
     milestone_and_events_reminders MAER
     ON MAE.id = MAER.milestone_and_events_id AND 
        MAER.issued = 0 AND 
        MAER.alert_time < "' . $currentTime . '"            
WHERE MAE.completed = 0 AND MAER.reminder_type <> "onTime"
GROUP BY MAE.id, MAER.reminder_user_id, MAER.reminder_type;
```

Note:  I moved the condition `MAE.completed = 0` from the `on` clause to the `where` clause.  It does nothing in the `on` clause.  And, I changed the first key in the `group by` to match the `SELECT`.

The best indexes for this query are composite indexes :  `milestone_and_events(completed, id)` and `milestone_and_events_reminders(milestone_and_events_id, issued, alert_time, reminder_type)`.

My guess is that putting the `completed = 0` where it belongs will reduce the amount of data and improve the performance of the query.

Comment: I try to follow your advice and I  change index `milestone_and_events` to milestone_and_events(completed, id)` because _reminder_type_ is in other table. And I change little your query  replacing `MAE.id` by `MAER.milestone_and_events_id`. but it seems not working. Are there any methods to do this ?? thank you very much for your help :)